# Is the idea of color coins/open assets still alive? Are there any interesting projects ahead on this way?

Tags: colored-coins

Since Ethereum has taken the way for smart contracts, it seems to me that the color coins projects have been abandoned in favour of the Ethereum ecosystem. But I might be wrong. Are there any interesting projects still for this approach?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 5 different colored coins implementations on bitcoin that I'm aware of. The ones in active development include:

- Colu - They recently showed how their implementation can be used with the lightning network. https://www.colu.com/
- Chromaway - They've been running a lot of pilots with various banks and whatnot. http://chromaway.com/

There's also a slack channel for colored coins as well, which you can see here: http://coloredcoins.org/

So no, it's not dead and there's still plenty of development going on.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recent update you can check:
https://medium.com/colu/announcing-colored-coins-and-lightning-integration-8e54d5dbfd0e#.7nnuw98ne

> #### Problem:
>
> [...]
>
> Colored Coins assets have the same TPS, Transaction fees, and verification times as Bitcoin.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Solution:
>
> [...]
>
> Colu has built a version of Lightning Labs’s code that is Colored Coins compatible. It uses Lightning technology transfer digital assets in payment channels and using the bitcoin blockchain as a settlement layer and a dispute resolution mechanism that secures the assets.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Rather include the key points from the link so that the answer also remains useful if or when the linked site becomes unavailable. Link-only answers are considered low-quality and may be removed.